# Count the number of nodes of a doubly linked list using recursion

Tags: recursion, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Here is what I've done so far:

```
struct rep_list {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
}

typedef rep_list *list;

int length(const list lst) {
    if (lst->head == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        lst->head = lst->head->next;
        return 1 + length(lst);
    }
}
```

This works, but the head of the list the function accepts as a parameter gets changed. I don't know how to fix that.

I'm not allowed to change the function definition so it should always accept a list variable.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I tried to do what Tyler S suggested in the comments but I encountered another problem. If I create a node* variable at the beginning, it should point to lst->head. But then every recursive call to the function changes the value back to lst->head and I cannot move forward.

Comment: I think you need to create a temporary `node*` to avoid changing the state of the list. Seems like its being modified when you execute `lst->head = lst->head->next`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. See the edit I made.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a local node: just don't change the list head.  Instead, pass the **next** pointer as the recursion head.

```
int length(const list lst) {
    if (lst->head == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1 + length(lst->head-next);
    }
}
```

---

I see.  Okay; this gets a bit clunky because of the chosen representation.  You need a temporary variable to contain the remaining list.  This iscludes changing the head.

```
int length(const list lst) {
    if (lst->head == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        new_lst = new(list)
        new_lst->head = lst->head->next;
        var result = 1 + length(new_lst);
        free(new_lst)
        return result
    }
}
```

At each recursion step, you create a new list object, point it to the 2nd element of the current list, and continue.  Does this do the job for you?

Comment: I cannot do that as the function I'm asked to implement accepts a list parameter (rep_list*) and lst->head->next is a node*.

Comment: I tried that but I don't know how to deallocate the memory allocated for new_lst. That assuming that if I use delete after the return line is going to be ignored.

Also, what changes should I make to the if statement if I used this solution?

Thanks for your help. English is not my first language and I'm new to programming in case I make silly mistakes.

Comment: You need to separate the result computation from the return.  Put the memory deallocation in between.  I edited my example -- but be sure to look up the proper commands in your language; I don't know what you're using, so what I wrote is probably not perfect.

Comment: you need to change the function def. to accept node, not list

Comment: @Hatim: changing the function signature violates the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Although this solution is clunky and I hate it, its the only way I can see to accomplish what you're asking without modifying the method signature. We create a temporary `node *` as member data of the class and modify it when we start.

```
struct rep_list {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
}

node *temp = NULL;
bool didSetHead = false;

typedef rep_list *list;

int length(const list lst) {
    if ((didSetHead) && (lst->head != temp)) {
         temp = lst->head;
         didSetHead = false;
    }
    if (temp == NULL) {
        didSetHead = true;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        temp = temp->next;
        return 1 + length(temp);
    }
 }
```

Please note, I haven't tested this code and you may have to play with a bit, but the idea will work.